# Magnetic field of ideal toroidal solenoid

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, physics, vector-analysis

A torus of [major radius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus#Geometry) $b$ and [minor radius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus#Geometry) $a$ can be parametrized by $\mathbf{r}:[0,2\pi]^2\to\mathbb{R}^3$, $\mathbf{r}(u,v)$ $=(b+a\cos v)\cos u\mathbf{i}+(b+a\cos v)\sin u\mathbf{j}+a\sin v\mathbf{k}$. Given a point $\mathbf{x}$ outside the surface of the torus, I would like to calculate the following integral: $$\mathbf{B}(\mathbf{x})=\frac{\mu_0}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{IN \partial_v\mathbf{r}(u,v) \times(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{r}(u,v) )}{2\pi\|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{r}(u,v)\|^3}dudv $$where $\mu_0, I$ and $N$ are constant. A physical interpretation of the expression is as the magnetic field generated by a toroidal solenoid of $N$ loops flown through by a current of intensity $I$ but reduced to an ideal solenoid with a surface distribution of current.

We can chose $\mathbf{x}=x\mathbf{i}+z\mathbf{k}$ without loss of generality. I calculate $$ \partial_v\mathbf{r}(u,v) \times(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{r}(u,v))=(-az\sin v\sin u+a^2\sin u+ab\cos v\sin u)\mathbf{i}$$$$+(ax\cos v-ab\cos v\cos u-a^2\cos u+az\sin v\cos u)\mathbf{j}+ax\sin v \cos u\mathbf{k}$$and $$\|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{r}(u,v)\|^2=x^2-2x(b+a\cos v)\cos u+(b+a\cos v)^2+z^2-2az\sin v+a^2\sin v.$$Please correct me if my calculation are wrong.

By reasoning on the $u$ symmetry, I would say that the $x$ and $z$ component of the integral are zero, while I calculate the $y$ component $B_2(\mathbf{x})$ as$$\frac{\mu_0 IN}{8\pi^2}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{ax\cos v-ab\cos u\cos v-a^2\cos u+az\cos u\sin v}{(x^2-2x(b+a\cos v)\cos u+(b+a\cos v)^2+z^2-2az\sin v+a^2\sin v)^{3/2}}dudv.$$ Is everything correct until this point? If it is, how can we calculate this integral? I suspect that complex analysis, of which I have some little elements, may help, but I am not sure how... I heartily thank you for any answer!

P.S.: By using intuitive arguments and Ampère's circuital law, which I have never seen proved for surface currents, my textbook of physics shows that, for $x\in(b-a,b+a)$, $\mathbf{B}(x\mathbf{i})=-\frac{\mu_0 NI}{2\pi x}\mathbf{j}$, while the field is assumed to be zero outside the torus. I would not be amazed if the integral gave us these same values...

Comment: Honestly I find trying to derive B fields from the Biot-Savart law annoying for most applications, is there some reason you decided against amperés law?

Comment: @Triatticus Thank you for your comment. Some reasons are: I am interested in calculating the integral per se; I have never seen a (mathematically rigourous, by definition) proof of Ampère's law for surface currents; it is not clear to me why it is $0$ outside the torus...

Comment: Griffiths does the calculation (most of it I believe) in his electrodynamics book. Also, the field outside a torus/solenoid isn't actually zero, it's just much weaker than the internal field. Best way to get intuition for this is to draw a cross section of a solenoidal (along the main axis) coil and visualize a surface current as discrete currents.

Comment: @Triatticus Thanks for suggesting Griffith's! It rigourously proves, in examples 5.10, that a toroidal solenoid generated by a (piecewise smooth) curve rotating around an axis has an azimuthal (w.r.to the axis) component only. Nevertheless, to prove the desired $\mathbf{B}$, it uses Ampères's law...

Comment: ... which I have never see for surface currents, but only for [linear](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/227477/amp%c3%a8res-law-from-biot-savart-law-for-linear-currents-with-multivariate-calculus/227557#227557) and [tridimensional](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/234360/proof-of-amp%c3%a8res-law-from-the-biot-savart-law-for-tridimensional-current-distri/241101#241101) distributions of current.

Comment: Well I hope that's still helpful to you Griffiths is a pretty good author, most undergrads/grads like his books